# Stop a batch file using another batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taskkill

I have a batch file which starts a new batch file on a new cmd prompt using the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "start mybatch.bat"
```

The `mybatch.bat` process keeps on running until someone stops it. When we close this batch file using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal, it does the operation of collecting the coverage data and then comes out. After initiating the `mybatch` file I am doing some other process on the parent batch file and then I want to stop the `mybatch` file.

I tried using `taskkill` for closing the process using the command in the parent batch file:

```
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq c:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe - mybatch.bat"
```

The problem here is that it stops the batch file forcefully not allowing it to run the coverage process which would have happened if I had used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> manually. Any thoughts on how I could achieve stopping the mybatch file using the parent batch file?

Everything is done using a batch file. Any help is highly appreciated.

My main batch file looks something like:

```
start mybatch.bat
REM do something like copying files, running tests, etc
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq c:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe - mybatch.bat"
```

In the above code instead of doing `taskkill` what if I want to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the command prompt with windowtitle "c:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe - mybatch.bat" using the main batch file. Is it possible?

Comment: Show us the batchfiles.

Answer (score 4):

**test.bat**

```
@echo off
title mybatchfile
echo ...do something
```

**testkill.bat**

```
Taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq mybatchfile"
```

testkill.bat will kill the test.bat

But you have tried it already.

**UPDATED**

It cannot done to stop batch from another batch. But you can run a batch as service to set a process name then you can define what should do on start and stop. This service can kill from batch file.

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27144688/3496666)

Answer (score 1):

There is no thing like a "please do something"-message to an batchfile. You will have to emulate it, for example like this:

```
REM mybatch.bat
:loop
REM do useful things
if not exist "c:\triggerfile.tmp" goto :loop

del "c:\triggerfile.tmp"
REM do "postprocessing"
exit
```

In your main bat file instead of `taskkill` just `echo x>"c:\triggerfile.tmp"`

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented SendKey.exe utility(Delphi console app) which emulates key presses but its a part of the internal application. I tried the following command and it worked fine. App uses keybd_event Win32 calls.

> SendKey.exe -wn "TestLoop.bat" -ks "{CTRL+C}Y{ENTER}"

You could use [NirCmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendkeypress.html) sending keypresses I think should work.